# how to parse the data using json parser after get the respones?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I am getting below respond when I am use the:

```
NSString *jobSearchUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/Countries"];
NSLog(@"url for new articles is = %@",jobSearchUrlString);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jobSearchUrlString]];   

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if( request )
{
    RoutData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}
else
{
NSLog(@"RoutConnection is NULL");

}   
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{   
    [RoutData setLength: 0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [RoutData appendData:data];   
    NSString *thexml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:RoutData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>> laxman Route data <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< %@",thexml);

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: RoutData];
[xmlParser setDelegate: self];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
[xmlParser parse];
result = [soapResults dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
webdataParser  = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:result];
[webdataParser setDelegate:self];
[webdataParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
[webdataParser parse];


NSLog(@"---------->>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<--------- %@",resultData);




<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Countries</title>
  <id>http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/Countries</id>
  <updated>2012-02-25T09:36:30Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Countries" href="Countries" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/Countries(14)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2012-02-25T09:36:30Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Country" href="Countries(14)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Region" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Region" href="Countries(14)/Region" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Contact_
2012-02-25 15:06:29.393 SampleTest[335:f803] ---------->>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<--------- (null)
2012-02-25 15:06:29.395 SampleTest[335:f803] >>>>>>>>>> laxman Route data <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Countries</title>
  <id>http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/Countries</id>
  <updated>2012-02-25T09:36:30Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Countries" href="Countries" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/Countries(14)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2012-02-25T09:36:30Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Country" href="Countries(14)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Region" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Region" href="Countries(14)/Region" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Contact_Country" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Contact_Country" href="Countries(14)/Contact_Country" />
    <category term="HpSalesPortalMobileDBModel.Country" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int16">14</d:Id>
        <d:RegionId m:type="Edm.Byte">1</d:RegionId>
        <d:CountryName>France</d:CountryName>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://infra2appsmobile.cloudapp.net/Infra2Apps.svc/Countries(15)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2012-02-25T09:36:30Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Country" href="Countries(15)" />
```

How to parse the data to get the "Id", "RegionId" and "CountryName"?

Is there a way to parse the data for one element?

Comment: Your response is in XML, not JSON, so you need to use an XML parser rather than a JSON one. Perhaps checkout this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project or use NSXMLParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
     //U can Catch Ur data in this delegate And Set Condition Get data Witch U Want.
}
```